# Inconsistent behavior when executing New-WebServiceProxy in a loop

Tags: wcf, powershell, powershell-3.0, iis-express

I'm having a problem with a powershell script that I wrote to call a method on a WCF web service. The WCF service has a composite DataContract as its sole request parameter. We have recently modified the ServiceContract (by adding two new methods), but the new methods are not being called by the powershell script. Here is the original contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileSystemService {
    [OperationContract]
    HashFileResponse HashFile(HashFileRequest req);

    [OperationContract]
    void GenerateFiles(GenerateFilesRequest req);
}
```

And here is the new contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileSystemService {
    [OperationContract]
    HashFileResponse HashFile(HashFileRequest req);

    [OperationContract]
    void GenerateFiles(GenerateFilesRequest req);

    [OperationContract]
    ParseFilePathResponse ParseFilePath(ParseFilePathRequest req);

    [OperationContract]
    ArchiveParsedFileResponse ArchiveParsedFile(ArchiveParsedFileRequest req);
}
```

The GenerateFiles method is the one being called by the PowerShell script. We have not modified the GenerateFilesRequest DataContract at all, which is defined below:

```
[DataContract]
public class GenerateFilesRequest : BaseRequest {
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Baserequest is currently an empty class for future use (all our request data contracts use it):

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class BaseRequest {
}
```

Calling this method works consistently via other means; SoapUI, Fiddler and via WCF contracts defined throughout the application.

After adding the two new methods, our integration tests are failing due to the fact the powershell script fails to call the GenerateFiles method consistently within a loop (see error output).

When I initially wrote this script, I was having a similar issue running it (though it either consistently broke, or consistently worked) but I managed to get the service calls working by adding the -Namespace and -Class arguments to the New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet.

Context: We are running a powershell script on a developer's machine, connecting to a WCF service hosted in IISExpress. All developers experience the same issues.

Here's the original script (preferred) before my recent modifications (this was working fine, but now most calls fail):

```
$sqlServer=$args[0]

function CallFSS($Id) {
    $uri = "http://localhost:1234/FileSystemService.svc?wsdl"
    $srv = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace fssNS -Class fssClass
    $req = [fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest](New-Object fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest)
    $req.Id= $Id
    $response = $srv.GenerateFiles($req)
}

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=" + $sqlServer + ";Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlConnection.Open()

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "select Id FROM MyTable WHERE Status = 2"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$sqlResult = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

while ($sqlResult.Read()) {
    $Id = $sqlResult.GetInt32(0)
    Write-Host Generating files for Id $Id
    CallFSS $Id
}

$SqlCmd.Dispose()
$SqlConnection.Dispose()
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Here is an excerpt of the output from the script. As you can see, this is vastly inconsistent (**Lines marked like this succeed**):

```
Generating files for Id 1
Cannot convert argument "req", with value: "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest", for "GenerateFiles" to type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest": "Cannot convert the  "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest" value of type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest" to type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest"." At C:\SolutionPath\GENERATE_FILES.ps1:23 char:2
+     $response = $srv.GenerateFiles($req)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
Generating files for Id 2
Cannot convert argument "req", with value: "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest", for "GenerateFiles" to type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest": "Cannot convert the  "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest" value of type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest" to type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest"." At C:\SolutionPath\GENERATE_FILES.ps1:23 char:2
+     $response = $srv.GenerateFiles($req)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
**Generating files for Id 3**
Generating files for Id 4
Cannot convert argument "req", with value: "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest", for "GenerateFiles" to type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest": "Cannot convert the  "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest" value of type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest" to type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest"." At C:\SolutionPath\GENERATE_FILES.ps1:23 char:2
+     $response = $srv.GenerateFiles($req)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument Generating files for Id 8 Cannot convert argument "req", with value: "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest", for "GenerateFiles" to type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest": "Cannot convert the  "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest" value of type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest" to type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest"." At C:\SolutionPath\GENERATE_FILES.ps1:23 char:2
+     $response = $srv.GenerateFiles($req)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument  
**Generating files for Id 9**
**Generating files for Id 10**
**Generating files for Id 11**
Generating files for Id 12
Cannot convert argument "req", with value: "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest", for "GenerateFiles" to type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest": "Cannot convert the  "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest" value of type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest" to type "fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest"." At C:\SolutionPath\GENERATE_FILES.ps1:23 char:2
+     $response = $srv.GenerateFiles($req)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Sometimes, most calls pass, and only the odd-one fails.

Here's another version of the script, which uses the auto-generated namespaces from New-WebServiceProxy:

```
$sqlServer=$args[0]

function CallFSS($Id) {
    $uri = "http://localhost:1234/FileSystemService.svc?wsdl"
    $srv = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri
    $type = $srv.GetType().Namespace
    $datatype = ($type + '.GenerateFilesRequest')
    $req = New-Object($datatype)
    $req.Id = $Id
    $response = $srv.GenerateFiles($req)
}

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=" + $sqlServer + ";Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
$SqlConnection.Open()

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "select Id FROM MyTable WHERE Status = 2"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$sqlResult = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()

while ($sqlResult.Read()) {
    $Id = $sqlResult.GetInt32(0)
    Write-Host Generating files for Id $Id
    CallFSS $Id
}

$SqlCmd.Dispose()
$SqlConnection.Dispose()
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Again, the results are inconsistent, though the error I get now relates to the auto-generated namespace:

```
**Generating files for Id 1**
**Generating files for Id 2**
Generating files for Id 3
Cannot convert argument "req", with value:  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3234_FileSystemService_svc_wsdl.GenerateFilesRequest", for "GenerateFiles"  to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3234_FileSystemService_svc_wsdl.GenerateFilesRequest": "Cannot  convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3234_FileSystemService_svc_wsdl.GenerateFilesRequest" value of  type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3234_FileSystemService_svc_wsdl.GenerateFilesRequest" to type  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3234_FileSystemService_svc_wsdl.GenerateFilesRequest"." At C:\SolutionPath\GENERATE_FILES.ps1:23 char:2
+     $response = $srv.GenerateFiles($req)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
Generating files for Id 4
Cannot convert argument "req", with value: "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3234_FileSystemService_svc_wsdl.GenerateFilesRequest", for "GenerateFiles"  to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3234_FileSystemService_svc_wsdl.GenerateFilesRequest": "Cannot  convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3234_FileSystemService_svc_wsdl.GenerateFilesRequest" value of  type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3234_FileSystemService_svc_wsdl.GenerateFilesRequest" to type  "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy3234_FileSystemService_svc_wsdl.GenerateFilesRequest"." At C:\SolutionPath\GENERATE_FILES.ps1:23 char:2
+     $response = $srv.GenerateFiles($req)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

Etc... execution is different every time.

I dearly hope this is something I'm doing wrong / misunderstanding as I am about to entirely give up on PowerShell. Is this maybe a caching issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you also post the GenerateFilesRequest data contract

Comment: @jisaak Sure, there you go. It's pretty simple and works fine when we call it via various other applications.

Comment: Thank you. Can you try to invoke the CallFSS like this: 1 .. 100 | % {Write-Host "Generating files for Id $_"; CallFSS $_ } and check whether there are still errors (just to ensure the error doesnt belong to the sql query)

Comment: Still getting the same error, though you have just taught me something cool :D 1, 2, 3 worked, 4 failed, 5 worked, 6 failed, 7 worked etc.

Comment: I implemented the GenerateFiles method with a 1 second sleep and then just return and do nothing and can call that method a hundert times without any error using your CallFSS method. Maybe the error is within the GenerateFiles method? You could try to empty the GenerateFiles method (just return) and check whether the error still exists

Comment: You could also try to get more error information using "$error[0] | select *".

Comment: I can reproduce the error using your data contract. However, if I delete the BaseRequest inherit. from GenerateFilesRequest, rebuild and RESTART the ISE, it works again

Comment: I've been using ISE and PowerShell power tools in VS, it happens in both. I've tried restarting ISE and VS, and IIS, but don't get any consistent behavior :|

Comment: Also, the GenerateFiles method works perfectly fine with other integration and UAT based testing - it's definitely the powershell call / script. It has something to do with the contracts generated by the proxy.

Comment: I will invest some time this evening and will write you if I find something

Comment: You're a star, thank you. I'm also playing with some of the tricks you've taught me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found something :)

I added an output for the GenerateFiles method definition within the CallFSS function:

```
$srv | gm -Name GenerateFiles | select -ExpandProperty Definition
```

Foreach successful request, the output was

> void GenerateFiles(fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest req)

The definition was different if I encountered an error:

> void GenerateFiles(fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest, oehlvn0y,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null req)

So if you create the object using the full qualified name, it should work:

```
function CallFSS($Id) 
{
    $uri = "http://localhost:11662/Service1.svc?wsdl"
    $srv = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace fssNS -Class fssClass 

    # Get the definition of the GenerateFiles method
    $definition = $srv | gm -Name GenerateFiles | select -ExpandProperty Definition

    # Extract the full qualified type name of the first parameter
    $paramType = [regex]::Match($definition, 'GenerateFiles\((.*)\s\w+').Groups[1].Value

    $bar = new-object $paramType
    $bar.Id = $Id

    $response = $srv.GenerateFiles($bar)
}
```

Note: This solution only works for methods with one parameter due to the regex. However, here is an implementation I would recommend:

```
function Invoke-FSS # Invoke is a valid Verb (see Get-Verb)
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,Position=0)]
        [int]$Id
    )

    Begin
    {
        $uri = "http://localhost:11662/Service1.svc?wsdl"
        $srv = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace fssNS -Class fssClass 

        # Get the definition of the GenerateFiles method
        $definition = $srv | gm -Name GenerateFiles | select -ExpandProperty Definition

        # Extract the full qualified type name of the first parameter
        $paramType = [regex]::Match($definition, 'GenerateFiles\((.*)\s\w+').Groups[1].Value
    }
    Process
    {        
        $bar = new-object $paramType
        $bar.Id = $Id
        $response = $srv.GenerateFiles($bar)
    }
    End
    {
        $srv.Dispose()
    }    
}
```

In your example, you would invoke the method by piping the ids to the `Invoke-FFS` method:

```powershell
$ids = @()
while ($sqlResult.Read()) {
    $ids += $sqlResult.GetInt32(0)
}

$ids | Invoke-FSS
```

The `Begin{}` block gets called only once (to initialize your proxy) and the `Process{}` block gets called for each item in `$ids`. Finally, the `End{}` block gets called once at the end to dispose the proxy gracefully.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow or Wed. Thank you for all your effort so far my man :)

Comment: Having problems running the Invoke-FSS call. "The Term 'Invoke-FSS' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.". Google's not helping. Any ideas?

Comment: I had a typo in the last code line ($ids | Invoke-FSS instead of Invoke-FFS). You can mark the whole Invoke-FSS function in your ISE and press F8. Then you should be able to test the function using "Invoke-FSS -Id 1"

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out - was about to post! Thanks, this seems to be working now - I'm just about to do a full end-to-end test with lots of data. I'll report back soon...

Comment: Started to play up intermittently again. Now either all calls succeed, or all calls fails with the following error: New-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'TypeName' because it is an empty string. Fails on the "$bar = new-object $paramType" part.

Comment: It's failing cos of the regex match. When it fails, $definition is "void GenerateFiles(fssNS.GenerateFilesRequest req)". i.e. its not fully qualified. This is basically the same issue as before - what the hell is going on here?

Comment: upps, you are right. Can you change the regex to: 'GenerateFiles\((.*)\s\w+'   this will capture both cases

Comment: Yep, but then it fails when the fully qualified name exists, due to the regex return group being empty. There are two scenarios - either a fully qualified name, or a static type name. Think an if statement is needed.

Comment: No, the regex will capture both cases. just try it. If it doesnt work, we can also try to check whether $paramType is empty and if yes, create the object the "old" way. But with the new regex it should work - i will update my post as well

Comment: I did try it! That is the case... it no longer works because there is no matching group. \s\w+ is the problem. Working it out now.

Comment: there is a '\' missing in my comment. Stackoverflow somehow removes it, just check the post

Comment: Ah no - got it. Your comment was missing the escape on the first bracket :) Its working for both scenarios now!

Comment: yeah, happy to hear that!

Comment: Thank you for all your time :) Any idea why it exhibits this behavior?

Comment: no problem, was interesting. unfortunately I have no clue why it exhibits this behavior.